# Maintain fonts size with different screen resolutions

Tags: jquery, css

What is the best practice/solution to maintain fonts size with different screen resolutions?

Comment: And different dpi and different monitor sizes, &c.—you can't since you don't have access to the low-level details to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that without access to information about the clients system, DPI and resolution. The best you can do in CSS is probably to use the `em` unit when dealing with font sizes, as it is in relation to the users default font size.

```
font-size: 0.8em;
```

Means that the font is 80% of the default font.

Answer (score 1):

For you to solve this, you'd have to know the **DPI** of the user's monitor. Using CSS "in" or "cm" units won't work, because those use a standard DPI of 72 or 96 (depending on the OS).

You can see why this isn't really solvable. Even if the monitor communicated its DPI via the two-way interface that DVI provides, that wouldn't be accessible from CSS or JavaScript. And what about two monitors of different resolutions? If you had a window straddling the gap what should happen then?

Mac OS X was long rumored to offer *"resolution independence"* but it hasn't showed up yet. Probably because it's a really hard problem.

Comment: ohh god i dont know what to do??